# How do I define a polymorphic type in Racket?

Tags: polymorphism, racket

I'm able to do things like `(def-structural T (args ....))}`, then apply T like a function in `base-env/base-types.rkt` (I mean, I can write `(T arg ...)`).

But I want to define `-HT` as a name for `(-poly (a b) (Un (T1 a b) (T2 a b)))` (for some `T1` `T2`).

I've tried `(define -HT (-poly ....))` and then I can't write `(-HT a b)` later in `base-env/base-types.rkt`.

Comment: To clarify: are you defining polymorphic types as a _User_ of the typed language, or as an _Implementer_ ? The notation you're using kinda looks like how an implementer would write types in [typed-racket], but I want to make sure